# CSS3 linear gradient not working properly on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, gradient

I created the CSS linear gradient code with Adobe FireWorks CS6. My grandient is supposed to be light blue at the top and dark blue at the bottom, on Chrome and safari it's all good, but on Firefox it is dark blue on the left and light blue on the right. I am new to html and CSS so I have no idea what could be wrong... I tried to change the -90deg to 90deg, 0deg, etc.. but nothing happens.. HELP!!!!

```
color: #FFF;
/* Firefox v3.6+ */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(50% 0% -90deg,rgb(101,165,227) 1%,rgb(0,78,157) 99%);
/* safari v4.0+ and by Chrome v3.0+ */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,50% 0%,50% 100%,color-stop(0.01, rgb(101,165,227)),color-stop(0.99, rgb(0,78,157)));
/* Chrome v10.0+ and by safari nightly build*/
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(101,165,227) 1%,rgb(0,78,157) 99%);
/* Opera v11.10+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(101,165,227) 1%,rgb(0,78,157) 99%);
/* IE v10+ */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(101,165,227) 1%,rgb(0,78,157) 99%);
background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(101,165,227) 1%,rgb(0,78,157) 99%);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff65a5e3,endColorstr=#ff004e9d,GradientType=0)";
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff65a5e3,endColorstr=#ff004e9d,GradientType=0);
line-height: 60px;
height: 60px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using it this way, its simple and hope this may help you. 
 All the Best !

```
    <div style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FE1C4A 22%, #AB244A 61%);
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FE1C4A 22%, #AB244A 61%);
         width: 200px; height: 100px; text-align: center;">
    </div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of inline css.

Comment: THANK YOU! Life savior! Worked like a charm ;)
I am a designer not a programmer, so I use Dreamweaver and Fireworks to create websites, the code is a mess sometimes.. This way is sooooo much easier!

Comment: Thanks, for all these compliments :)

Answer (score 14):

Many web examples will give an example using the standardized `linear-gradient` function that will look just like this:

```
linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(73,132,180) 0%, rgb(97,155,203) 100%);
```

Note however, that using bottom, top or similar keywords is not actually part of the standard, you have to use either a degree value such as `0deg`, `-90deg`, etc. or apply the `to`  prefix like `to bottom`, `to top` or `to left top`:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(73,132,180) 0%, rgb(97,155,203) 100%);
----------------^
```

Comment: This helped; thanks. For me, the issue was that Chrome is OK with the degree value not having a unit, but FF and IE are not. That is, you need to use 0deg, not just 0